# DevOps nuget pack step not picking up dll´s

Tags: c#, azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines

In the DevOps build pipeline I have the Pack Nuget step. I have a project that references other projects. I am trying to pack all dependent dll´s but the nuget step only picks up one of the dll´s .

What I have tried so far is the following:

> 1. $/BusinessLogic/BLL.PROJECTS/PROJECTA/PROJECTA.csproj;$/BusinessLogic/BLL.PROJECTS/PROJECTB/PROJECTB.csproj;
> 2. $/BusinessLogic/BLL.PROJECTS/***.csproj

Pattern 1 will only include PROJECTA.dll.

Pattern 2 will not find any projects.

What would be the correct path for this to work?
Since the build step is before, could I possibly pick the dll's from the binaries folder?

[image: N]

Comment: considering the path uses `/` to separate directories at the beginning of the text box, have you tried using `**/*.csproj` instead of `**\*.csproj`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the main `.csproj` that other projects referenced to him and in the "Pack options" section mark the checkbox "Include referenced projects":

[image]

Comment: Thanks @ShaykiAbramczyk this works, but is there a way to allow automatic package versioning as well or is it needed to manually set it in the assembly file?

Comment: You can change the value in the drop down from "off" to another value.

Comment: Hi @ShaykiAbramczyk the problem is if I change it to another value the "Include referenced projects" disappears. I was hoping I could do both?

Comment: @doorman You're right, you can't use the automatic versioning with this option :/ so you will need to do it manually with a script before the pack task.

Comment: Hi thanks I used the following syntax which will generate the versioning automatically [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.1.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.1.*")]

Comment: @doorman if you use the automatic versioning offered by DervOps pipelines, you simply need to modify your nuspec so that it includes this entry: `<version>$version$</version>`. DevOps knows how to poulate  it